# How can i speed up abiword 2.9.2 in xubuntu? It runs too slow.

Tags: xubuntu, abiword

abiword 2.8.6 in 11.10 was fine for me. After a 12.04 fresh install, abiword 2.9.2 is now available... and I definitly can't use it!

- scrolling the text with the mousewheel is impossible. It only works in the lift at the very right of the screen.
- everything is very slow. e.g. Ctrl + G (Go to page...) needs several seconds to display. It then needs a few more seconds before I can type the page number I want to reach
- the rule at the top of the text no more exists. A black line is dsplayed
- when going down in the texte, display briefly disapears (1 or 2 tenth of a second) between each new line

Since I definitly can't work with it, I restored 11.10.
Abiword website tell version 2.9.2 is unstable and should not be used
I think about a compatibility problem with GTK
Do you know more about that ?

Answer (score 1):

You might consider asking the Abiword team.  Where did you get your installed version?  You should always go for the version presented in the Ubuntu Software Centre.  If you got it anywhere else then get rid of it and re-install from the Ubuntu Software Centre.  If the problem is with the Abiword Ubuntu package, report this as a bug using ubuntu-bug abiword in the terminal.

Answer (score 1):

I stumbled upon this question while looking for info myself and found a [bug report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/abiword/+bug/1019621) that provides further details.

The solution might be to use an [appropriate PPA](https://launchpad.net/~mrpouit/+archive/ppa?field.series_filter=precise) to revert to a stable release of Abiword.